# Trouble calling SQL data and set information in C# variable

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I've written a program that sends email data from the database (SQL Server)

```
public int MailServerID { get; set; }
public string MailServerUserName { get; set; }
public string MailServerUserPassword { get; set; }
public string MailServerSMTPServerName { get; set; }
public bool MailServerRequiredSSL { get; set; }
public int MailServerSMTPPortNumber { get; set; }
public bool MailServerActive { get; set; }
public string MailServerDescription { get; set; }
```

These are my variables.

```
public List<csMailServer> GetMailServerDetailsActive()
{
    List<csMailServer> MyList = new List<csMailServer>();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DbCommand MyCommand = GozargahCRUD.CreateCommandProcedure();
    try
    {
        MyCommand.CommandText = "sp_GetMailServerDetailsActive";
        DbParameter param;

        param = MyCommand.CreateParameter();
        param.DbType = DbType.Int32;
        param.ParameterName = "@Ret";
        param.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
        MyCommand.Parameters.Add(param);

        dt = GozargahCRUD.ExecuteReader(MyCommand);

        MyList = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows

                     select new csMailServer()
                      {
                          MailServerID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["MailServerID"]),
                          MailServerUserName = dr["MailServerUserName"].ToString(),
                          MailServerUserPassword = dr["MailServerUserPassword"].ToString(),
                          MailServerSMTPServerName = dr["MailServerSMTPServerName"].ToString(),
                          MailServerRequiredSSL = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["MailServerRequiredSSL"]),
                          MailServerSMTPPortNumber = Convert.ToInt32(dr["MailServerSMTPPortNumber"]),
                          MailServerActive = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["MailServerActive"]),
                          MailServerDescription = dr["MailServerDescription"].ToString()
                      }).ToList();

        return MyList;
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
         throw;
    }
}
```

And that's my server-side code

Here, it only sends the data that is TRUE, which is only one data

So far, all the things are working properly, and the procedure works well

But when I call the `SendMail` method:

```
public bool SendMail(string to, string subject, string body)
{
    try
    {
        GetMailServerDetailsActive();
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        message.From = new MailAddress(MailServerUserName,"Exynos Support");
        message.To.Add(to);
        message.Subject = subject;
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        message.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
        message.Body = body;

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(MailServerSMTPServerName);
        client.Port = MailServerSMTPPortNumber;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(MailServerUserName , MailServerUserPassword);
        client.EnableSsl = Convert.ToBoolean(MailServerRequiredSSL);
        client.Send(message);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception Err)
    {
         throw;
    }
}
```

The variables that are defined above the code are empty

What is the problem?

Thanks All!

Comment: which variables?

Comment: You create objects and return them but don’t store them anywhere. That’s at least one problem. But it’s hard to see from here which class these methods are in etc

Comment: The method for getting information from the database works fine But Data that is received from the database will not remain in the properties for use with the SendMail method.

Comment: @Mojtaba, where did you call this `SendMail(string to, string subject, string body)` method?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating the MyList object and returning it, but the caller isn't doing anything with it. You want to set the values of the public properties instead.

It sounds like the data table will only ever contain one row. In that case, you don't need a list at all - just the one data row from the data table.

First, change the return type of GetMailServerDetailsActive to void.

Then change this:

```
    MyList = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows

              select new csMailServer()
              {
                  MailServerID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["MailServerID"]),
                  MailServerUserName = dr["MailServerUserName"].ToString(),
                  MailServerUserPassword = dr["MailServerUserPassword"].ToString(),
                  MailServerSMTPServerName = dr["MailServerSMTPServerName"].ToString(),
                  MailServerRequiredSSL = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["MailServerRequiredSSL"]),
                  MailServerSMTPPortNumber = Convert.ToInt32(dr["MailServerSMTPPortNumber"]),
                  MailServerActive = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["MailServerActive"]),
                  MailServerDescription = dr["MailServerDescription"].ToString()
              }).ToList();
return MyList;
```

To this:

```
DataRow dr = dt.Rows[0];
MailServerID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["MailServerID"]);
MailServerUserName = dr["MailServerUserName"].ToString();
MailServerUserPassword = dr["MailServerUserPassword"].ToString();
MailServerSMTPServerName = dr["MailServerSMTPServerName"].ToString();
MailServerRequiredSSL = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["MailServerRequiredSSL"]);
MailServerSMTPPortNumber = Convert.ToInt32(dr["MailServerSMTPPortNumber"]);
MailServerActive = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["MailServerActive"]);
MailServerDescription = dr["MailServerDescription"].ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you, it was a major problem
Thank You